# What's the minimum number of vertices in a simple graph with $e$ edges

Tags: graph-theory

Describe the minimum number of vertices in a simple graph (no loops or multiple edges) with $e$ edges.

I can't derive a formula for this, I don't even know if this is possible.

Anyway, it's not hard to see that the complete graph is the one that optimizes the use of vertices, for example the minimum for $e=3$ is the number of vertices en $K_3$, the minimum for $e=6$ is the number of vertices in $K_4$, the minimum for $e=10$ is the number of vertices in $K_5$ and so on...so I would know this:

If $2 \leq e \leq 3$ the minimum is $3$

If $4 \leq e \leq 6$ the minimum is $4$

If $7 \leq e \leq 10$ the minimum is $5$ and so on...

But I can't see how to derive a formula...is that possible? If so, how?

Comment: It seems relevant that each edge connects two vertices, and that $\binom{3}{2} = 3$, $\binom{4}{2} = 6$, $\binom{5}{2} = 10$.

Answer (score 2):

The maximum number of edges in an $n$-vertex simple graph is $\binom n2=\frac{n(n-1)}2=T_{n-1}$ where $T_n$ denotes the $n$th triangular number. It is possible to find $n$ given $T_n$ using what is known as a *triangular root*:
$$n=\frac{\sqrt{8T_n+1}-1}2$$
Hence the smallest number of vertices that will support a graph with $e$ edges is
$$\left\lceil\frac{\sqrt{8e+1}-1}2+1\right\rceil$$
which can be simplified to
$$\left\lceil\sqrt{2e}+\frac12\right\rceil$$
$\lceil x\rceil$ denotes the ceiling function, the smallest integer greater than or equal to $x$.